# Android: NPE when retrieving a String resource

Tags: android, string, resources

Since a few weeks I started receiving crash report for my app.
The exception is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:292)

My code is :

> this.service.getString(R.string.download);

where service is not null and R.string.download exists

I tested my code on 4 devices and it works fine.
It looks like the resources are corrupted on a few user install.

Any idea how this can happen ? Or to avoid this ?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:292) can you show us the code

Comment: this is Android 4.0.4 source code.
It looks like the resource R.java class is corrupted on this user install